# How to accept only number in the input field using js

Tags: javascript

How to make the input box accept only numbers in the input field using js event listener.

```
  <form action="#">
     <label for="value">Value:</label>
     <input type="text" name="value" id="value" />
     <button type="submit">Convert</button>
     <button type="reset">Clear</button>
  </form>
 

<script>
    form.addEventListener(`submit`, function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });    
</script>
```

Comment: You can change `type="text"`  to `type="number"`

Comment: You can use typeof parseInt(input) == „number“. This will try to parse the input to a number and then check if parseint returns a number or something else using typeof

Comment: And remember that anyone can open developer tools to get around any client side validation you attempt to make. Always double-check that your inputs are valid on your server-side code before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the input to a number and then check if it is a number or something else like NaN.

```
if(typeof parseInt(input) ==="number"){
  console.log("number!");
}
```

Please note that anyone can bypass this using the dev tools so don't forget to implemnt server-side validation.(Thx for the tip @samathingamajig)